# Referência a estilos e script's na Master.Page usando ResolveUrl

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Na Master.Page faço referências aos estilos e script´s que serão herdados pelas demais páginas através do ResolveUrl.

```
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/") %>Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/") %>Scripts/jQuery-Mask-Plugin.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/") %>Scripts/jQuery-Formatacao.js" type='text/javascript'></script>

<link href="<%# ResolveUrl("~/") %>Styles/estilo.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Vi alguns post´s que sugerem inserir o código abaixo para que a referência inicial possa  ser efetiva:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

Isto é realmente necessário?

Estou usando o framework 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tags `<%# %>` são utilizadas para [vinculação de dados](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860/pt-br#1), e portanto é necessário que o código execute a vinculação (`DataBind()`) no caso dela não ser feita automaticamente (como acontece nos controles de vinculação de dados). Você pode optar por usar as tags `<%: %>`, sem a necessidade de usar o segundo bloco de código que está no enunciado da sua pergunta.

No caso, o código ficaria assim:

```
<script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js") %>" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jQuery-Mask-Plugin.js") %>" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jQuery-Formatacao.js") %>" type='text/javascript'></script>

<link href="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Styles/estilo.css") %>" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

No caso de dúvidas futuras, eis a explicação do funcionamento das tags do ASP.NET:

`<% %>` define um bloco de código do servidor que é executado durante a renderização da página. Pode executar declarações e chamar métodos da classe da página em que o bloco está inserido (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

`<%= %>` funciona como um `Response.Write()`, mais útil para exibir informações únicas (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx).

`<%# %>` define uma expressão de vinculação de dados (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

`<%$ %>` define uma expressões do ASP.NET (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

`<%@ %>` define uma expressão de diretiva (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e%28VS.80%29.aspx).

`<%-- --%>` define um bloco de comentários do lado do servidor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4acf8afk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

`<%: %>` funciona como o `<%= %>`, mas codifica a saída em HTML (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2).

Você pode checar mais detalhes dessas expressões em:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

## Referência

Baseado na resposta do usuário mbanavige nos fóruns do ASP.NET.
<URL: http://forums.asp.net/t/1139381.aspx>

Comment: Muito obrigado, muito esclarecedor o post. No exemplo você usou o "#" para <%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js") e o ":" para os demais, foi algum engano ou tem de ser assim mesmo?

Comment: Opa, foi um engano. Desculpe-me.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado!